# Tracking open files using WMI Notification events

Tags: php, windows-server-2008-r2, wmi-query, adsi

I've created an internal web page for my company that lists open files via ADSI objects and while it works well, it takes time to load and is difficult and time-consuming to filter, if the filter works at all.

The core of this PHP script follows.

```
$lms=new COM('WinNT://file-server/LanmanServer');

$files=array();
foreach ($lms->Resources as $key => $value) {
    try {
        $files[$value->Path]=$value->User;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo '<!-- ', $e->getMessage(), ' -->',"\n";
    }
}
```

My question is this - is there a WMI object equivalent to this method?  One that lists the full file (not just the share, so Win32_ServerConnection is not the answer here!) and who opened it, same as the Shared Folders snapin and the ADSI object used above?  If there is, I'd like to use a notification event to put that data into a SQL database table where it can be queried and filtered quickly.